# Apex getter returning wrong value

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex-code

I have javascript function in my salesforce page to validate if one of the contacts have open cases. This function calls an apex getter to get the value. The problem I`m facing is that the apex getter is always returning the wrong boolean. I tried debugging it, everything seems to work but for some reason the returned bool is wrong.

apex function:

```
 public Boolean openCase{
   get{

        if (Contacts.size() > 0){
            for(cContact wContact: dicContacts.values()){
                 if(wContact.selected){                     
                     if(wContact.con.account.Number_of_open_Financial_Review_Cases__c > 1){

                        return true;
                    } 
                 }           
            }                     
    return false;
   }
   set{}

}
```

js function:

```
 function validateOpenCases(sendEmail){

    doIt = true;
    oc = {!openCase};   // <<== problem here
    alert(oc);
      if (oc)
      {
       doIt=confirm('blabla?');
      }
      if(doIt){
            // do stuff
      }
      else{
        // do nothing
      }
  }
```

Comment: its supposed to be a boolean no?

Comment: I believe so" `var oc = openCase();` would make more sense, imo.

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not bind Apex objects/variables directly in JavaScript (like you have `{!openCase};`). I've had many issues with this before. Instead use [JavaScript Remoting](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_CSH.htm#pages_js_remoting_example.htm) or the [Ajax Toolkit](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/index_CSH.htm#sforce_api_ajax_calls.htm).

---

### **Update**

Another option is to use a hidden Visualforce input to store your bound Visualforce value. Then you can get that value in your JavaScript.

Here's an example:

```
<apex:page controller="myController">
    <script>
        function getInputEndingWith(endsWith)
        {
            // put together a new Regular Expression to match the 
            // end of the ID because Salesforce prepends parent IDs to
            // all elements with IDs
            var r = new RegExp("(.*)"+endsWith+"$"); 

            // get all of the input elements
            var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

            // initialize a target
            var target;

            // for all of the inputs
            for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i)
            {
                // if the ID of the input matches the
                // Regular Expression (ends with)
                if (r.test(inputs[i].id))
                {
                    // set the target
                    target = inputs[i];
                    // break out of the loop because target 
                    // was found
                    break; 
                }
            }

            // return the target element
            return target;
        }

        function validateOpenCases(sendEmail)
        {
            doIt = true;
            oc = getInputEndingWith("OpenCase").value;

            alert(oc);

            if (oc === "true") {
                doIt = confirm('Are you sure?'); 
            }
            if (doIt) {
                // do stuff
            }
            else {
                // do nothing
            }
        }
    </script>

    <apex:form>
        <apex:outputpanel>
            <apex:inputhidden id="OpenCase" value="{!openCase}" />
        </apex:outputpanel>
        <input type="button" class="btn" onclick="validateOpenCases('Send');" value="Validate" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: How can I use that? I'm still new in Salesforce, and I didn't find a lot of examples for JavaScript remoting or Ajax tool kit. Can you give me a hint on how to apply it?

Comment: I just realized one of the links I supplied wasn't working correctly, here's a better one, and it has an example: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=pages_js_remoting_example.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fpages_js_remoting_example.htm|SkinName=webhelp.

Comment: Here's a Ajax toolkit example too: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/Content/sforce_api_ajax_introducing.htm#sforce_api_ajax_sample_scontrol

Comment: JavaScript remoting didnt work well for me because I had to make most of my variables to static which doesnt work well for my application.

Comment: Thank you. I have on issue though, what's `myHiddenInput` and how come you are not using the parameter passed in `getInputEndingWith(endsWith)` and whats this used for `if (/(.*)WidgetName$/g.exec(inputs[i].id))`.

Comment: Those were variables I forgot to change when I pasted the code in the answer.. They're fixed now.

Comment: It worked but apex:inputhidden has some issues so I used a normal input html field and set it to hidden.